# Do graph homomorphisms preserve forests?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, matroids

A [graph homomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_homomorphism) $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ is an *adjacency preserving* map between graphs $G$ and $H$. In other words, if $u,v\in V(G)$ are adjacent in $G$, written $u\sim v$, then we must have $\phi(u)\sim \phi(v)$ in $H$.

Any graph $G$ is a [matroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid#Definition) $M=(E,\mathcal{I})$, where the ground set $E$ is the set of edges $E(G)$ and the independent sets $I\in\mathcal{I}$ are the [forests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Forest) (disjoint collections of trees) $F\subset E(G)$. To give more intuition, the dependent sets in a graph (as a matroid) are its cycles.

A (possible) definition of a matroid homomorphism is a map $\varphi: M \rightarrow N$, between matroids $M$ and $N$ which *preserves independence*, in the sense that if $I$ is independent in $M$, then $\varphi(I)$ must be independent in $N$.

**Note:** in graph theory the term *independent set* is often used synonymously with the term *[coclique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)#:%7E:text=In%20the%20mathematical%20area%20of,its%20induced%20subgraph%20is%20complete.)* (or stable sets). In this context, I mean an [independent set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid#Independent_sets) in the matroid sense i.e. a forest when referring to a graph.

**Question:** Let  $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ be an adjacency preserving map between graphs, is the image of each forest, $F$ in $G$, a forest $\phi(F)$ in $H$?

I think that one should consider non-simple graphs since loops are quite relevant in matroids.

**Follow up question:** Is there a study of forest preserving mappings between graphs? Or does this all get subsumed by graph minors?

Comment: Graph *homomorphisms* are much less often relevant in graph theory than someone from an algebraic background would expect. They have their place, but usually we care much more about subgraphs (injective homomorphisms) which, incidentally, do have the property you want.

Comment: Interesting! Can you answer the question and prove that injective graph homomorphisms preserve forests?

Comment: Wait no, I'm lying. We always have an adjacency preserving map from $G$ to the complete graph $K_n$ on the same number of vertices, but the complete graph is not a forest. (Unless $\phi(G)$ is defined more carefully - what exactly are the edges of $\phi(G)$?)

Comment: I guess this is why we have graph minors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. Let $G$ be a graph on $\{0,1,2,\ldots, 19\}$ where there is an edge between $i$ and $j$ iff $|i-j|=1$ [no wraparound]. So 19 is adjacent to precisely 18, and 0 to precisely 1, and every other vertex has degree 2. This is a forest, a tree to be precise, actually a path on 20 vertices.

Then consider the mapping $\phi: G \mapsto \{0,1,2,3\}$ where $\phi(i) = i \mod 4$.
Then $\phi(G)$ is a 4-cycle.

Comment: right, if you allow loops, this even works with the graph with one edge $e=(u,v)$, the map $u\mapsto v'$ and $v\mapsto v'$ with $e'=(v',v')$ preserves adjacency but sends $e$ to a loop (i.e. it maps an independent set to a dependent one).

Comment: Yes indeed it does. But I wasn't positive if the definition insists that adjacent distinct vertices in $G$ get mapped to adjacent *distinct* vertices in $H$, so I used this counter-example just in case.